# Simplify the matrix using row-column transformations to get $2(\cos \theta)( \lambda^2 + \lambda + 1)$

Tags: determinant, matrix-equations

$$
        \begin{vmatrix}
        \sin \theta & -\cos \theta & \lambda+1 \\
        \cos \theta & \sin \theta & -\lambda \\
        \lambda & \lambda +1 & \cos \theta \\
        \end{vmatrix} = 2(\cos \theta)( \lambda^2 + \lambda + 1)
$$

Attempt: Dividing R1 and R2 by sin $\theta $ and cos $\theta $, and then doing  R2 -> R2-R3 and R1-> R1-R3
But it would still be complicated to solve the equation.

Comment: Are you asking $2\cos(\theta(\lambda^2+\lambda+1))$ or $2(\lambda^2+\lambda+1)\cos\theta$?

Comment: Why don't you just expand the determinant?? It will be easy.

Comment: @AlgorithmsX it is the latter.

Comment: 2 cos θ (λ2 + λ + 1) @AlgorithmsX

Comment: @Rohan It is supposed to be done using Row/Column transformations. I know it can be expanded and be done using Trigonometric Transformations, but since the matrix looks like it can be solved using R/C Transformations...